# anyone know how to install gtk3 for anaconda/spyder? on windows

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried installing  gtk3 through pip install, and anaconda install for the different packages. Through spyder and anaconda console.
I tried

```
$ conda install -c conda-forge gtk3 

$ conda install -c conda-forge pygobject
```

however when i run this code

```
import gi
gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
from gi.repository import Gtk
import data
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_gtkagg import FigureCanvasGTKAgg as FigureCanvas
import gobject

Result
  File "C:\Users\bboyn\Desktop\coding\python\cpu monitor\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    import gi

  File "D:\python\lib\site-packages\gi\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi

ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Comment: `D:\python\lib\site-packages\gi_init_.py` this looks like the `gi` package is not installed in the conda environment but either `main.py` is run from a different python interpreter or the `gi` module is loaded via a different mechanism such as `PYTHONPATH`. Packages you installed with conda won't be visible that way.